# Limit current without fuse or breaker

Tags: dc, amperage

I'm looking for a way to 'cap' current coming from my solar panels.

I have two panels, 300 W each. In sunny conditions that would provide 18 A @ 33 V. In cloudy conditions that provides ~4 A @ 33 V.

Basically, I want to leave both panels connected to the circuit at all times, and 'cap' amps at 10 A. This limits the speed my battery is charged, and ensures all the wiring stays under their defined amp limitations.

I know that a fuse or breaker can do this, but I have to manually replace/reset them. Is there a circuit/resistor that can do this?

I've been reading up on DC-DC converters that can control voltage & amperage, but I'm not sure that will work in my case.

My Setup:(for completeness)

Panels -> "current limiter" -> Charge Controller -> battery

**Please do not suggest changing the charge controller or asking for specs on the charge controller. I don't want to talk about the charge controller. I want to learn what is possible circuitry wise!**

---

Edits:

After looking into videos on DC-DC converters, I see that they will drop the voltage in order to provide the "set" amperage limit. So if I set the amperage limit to 10 amps, I need the output voltage to be at least ~14.4 or more volts. That means I need a minimum of 144 Watts into the buck converter, or the battery wont charge at all. On a cloudy day I'm usually in the range of 40 - 120 watts, so that will not work for me at all.

What I would need is a dynamically changing buck converter, output the exact same amperage that is input, don't try to increase the amperage, whilst capping amperage at 10 A.

I was hoping there was something simple, like how a charge controller works. Say I had full sun, 18 Amps coming in, but the charge controller knows my battery is full! or almost full. So it only lets out say ~1 amp. What is the electrical circuitry providing that function, it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139680/discussion-on-question-by-2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5-limit-amps-without-fuse).

Comment: Charge controllers will limit the current to batteries according to thier state of charge. Just make sure that the charge controller settings match the battery chemistry.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm worried about longevity. my charge controller can do 18 A when my battery is dead, but I don't want it to charge that fast

Comment: If you are worried about longevity then don't discharge the batteries that low. DEAD is not good for batteries of ANY type.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, poor phrasing on my part as usual. I never discharge below 30% as a MAX. Still, even if 70% full, the CC will put too many amps to my battery.

Comment: downvote reason? Is it a duplicate, is the question unclear, as someone new to this area, I tried to explain what I was looking for info on as best I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is limit the current, the most straightforward way to do that is with a current source. "Current source" is perhaps a bit of a misnomer, as they are not ideal; a current source maintains a constant current as long as the voltage required to do so doesn't exceed the supply voltage. So if the load is too high impedance, or the source too low voltage, the current will be lower than the nominal current of the current source.

However, complex electronics like charge controllers might not appreciate their supply being so limited. This is one reason people were asking you for details on the charge controller; many electronic circuits draw a large amount of inrush current when first turned on or when reactivating from a sleep mode, and if a source can't supply this inrush current, they may fail to operate.

Something like a PTC thermistor could allow brief inrush surges and still limit the current, as their limiting functionality is a function of temperature and it takes time for things to heat up. However, because it's a function of temperature, it's difficult to calculate exactly *how* the current will be limited; it will depend on ambient conditions like temperature and airflow.

---

A response to your edit posted while I was typing this:

Yes, the voltage must be decreased to limit current. There is, quite simply, no other way to do it. Voltage and current are inextricably linked; for a given load under the same conditions, the same voltage will result in the same current and vice versa (bar some exotic things which may have two stable currents at the same voltage or vice versa).

This is another reason people were asking you for details on your charge controller. Certain types of power supplies and charge controllers will attempt to keep their output the same by drawing *more* current when the input voltage drops. The current source then won't allow this increased current, dropping the voltage further, whereupon the charger tries to pull even more current, which rapidly results in the voltage being dropped almost to zero, and the current source most likely overheating and turning into a fuse anyway.

---

Really, the root problem here is that most things expect to be powered by something that is approximately a voltage source, not a current source. While simple loads like resistors or light bulbs might be fine with a current source (and some things like LEDs actually prefer them), most complex circuits (particularly those involving DC-DC converters) won't react well to being powered by a current source. I could speculate for ages as to what exactly might happen, and it might even work fine, but, as much as you might not like to hear it, *the proper solution to this is to design the charge controller to limit the current itself*.

Comment: I was hoping below 10 A I could just passthrough, and not mess with the voltage amperage, and when over 10A just cap it. Heat would definitely be a problem, since the system could theoretically output 18 A, I had assumed I would need a couple bulk converters in parallel.

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 The heat generated will be a function of the actual current, not the potential current. If you hook up a 500 W heater to a mains circuit capable of providing 1 kW, it'll still only produce 500 W of heat. But any device is going to consume power equal to the current through the device multiplied by the voltage across the device, and in most cases immediately convert that power to heat. (Sometimes it'll convert some of it to light, or sound, or physical motion, depending on what it's designed to do, though.)

Comment: is there a "dynamic" current limiter? IE. Lets the current flow freely when < 10 A but converts anything additional to heat?

I'd be looking at ~300 watts of heat assuming peak power. Sounds like a lot of cooling would be needed.

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 That's what the current sources I mention in my answer do. But I don't think those will work for you, because of what I've just added to my answer: it'll almost certainly mess with the control system of your charge controller to power it with a current source.

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding somewhere as to how electricity works. I'm not sure where exactly or I'd have more to say to help, sorry.

Comment: likely true :) Likely why breakers and fuses are suggested for this problem, its not something that is straightforward to do by the sounds of it. Only way to overcome it is to design the system based on max inputs. Get the right amount of batteries to handle the maximum the panels + charge controller could provide. I would need a 70 A charge controller and 3 x 100 AH batteries to provide max 25% of AH capacity as charge current to improve battery longevity. All of that seems extremely overkill, but solar seems to be this way.

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 Are you sure your charge controller doesn't have a function to limit current? I'm not familiar with solar stuff but I would think they would.

Comment: I've seen some that let you limit the voltage to the battery only. I think there are some very high end Victron systems that let you specify max current

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 That's surprising, as it's actually dangerous to charge batteries too quickly. Are you sure that's not a function they have that you just haven't found?

Comment: I agree, hence the question. Again, I've seen it on some high-end controllers, but it certainly doesn't seem to be a common feature

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since the charge controller can't be changed and we can't discuss even it, you can do this:

You can add a second PWM chopper between the solar panel and charge controller. This PWM chopper would have a Hall current sensor. If the sensor indicates less than let's say 9.5 amperes, the charge controller would be continuously connected. If it shows 9.5 - 10 amperes, you will start to PWM modulate the connection (with 9.5 amperes having 100% PWM time and 10 amperes having 0% PWM time). If it shows 10 amperes or more, you will not allow current through at all anymore (except then the Hall sensor will read zero amps, and once the averaging period indicates less than 10 amperes, you will allow current again).

The PWM modulator is simple: you will convert the current to a voltage, and add some time delay averaging (let's say with a capacitor and resistor), let's say 9.5 amperes = 9.5 volts, 10 amperes = 10 volts. Then you compare it to a sawtooth wave between 9.5 and 10 volts. If let's say you have 9.75 volts, then half of the time the sawtooth wave is below 9.75 volts and half of the time it's above 9.75 volts. So 9.75 volts would give 50% duty cycle.

The averaging period of course needs to be much longer than the PWM frequency. I would recommend a frequency of 50-100 kHz, that's above the audible range so won't cause audible noise, but below the frequencies at which circuit design would be harder.

The averaging period could be much longer, let's say even 1 millisecond.

There's of course the possibility that this PWM chopper would interact badly with the charge controller. It depends on the design of the charge controller and whether it's PWM or MPPT.

If the fact that the current is chopped, not continuous, annoys you, you can add an inductor to cause averaging for the current. Then you would essentially have a switched mode power supply. In that case it might be questionable why you would even want to use a second charge controller, why not just replace the charge controller by the PWM+inductor circuit you designed.

Comment: Lots for me to take away research here, thanks!
I was hoping there was something simple, like how a charge controller works. Say I had full sun, 18 Amps coming in, but the charge controller knows my battery is full! or almost full. So it only lets out say ~1 amp. What is the electrical circuitry providing that function, it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for

Comment: Well a PWM charge controller is very similar to a PWM current controller, only PWM charge controller measures voltage and chops the signal based on it, whereas a PWM current controller measures current (usually with a Hall sensor) and chops the signal based on it. The PWM is done using a sawtooth comparator, as I said. There are plenty of integrated circuits that can do that today, due to the prevalence of switched-mode power supplies that do something similar.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to let the magic smoke out of the OP's charge controller...

Comment: lol I mean in theory its what i'm looking for. PWM charge controller chops the voltage, I also want to chop the amperage. Just nothing on the market that I can find to do so.

Comment: I agree that the CC probably can't handle intermittent current like that

Comment: If intermittent current is a problem for the charge controller, you can add the inductor and then you would essentially have a buck converter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter -- buck converter has continuous limited current.